# How to set title on the navigation bar for different buttons on a single view?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

My app for iPad has 3 views. Welcome Screen -> Home screen -> Detail screen

Home screen has 6 buttons. All those buttons have different data which is shown on detail screen respective to the button pressed. I want to set a title for each button on the navigation bar of the Detail Screen. So there will be 6 titles on the navigation bar. I have tagged the buttons from 1 to 6.
pls guide
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Navigation Controller, then all you need is to set `title` property of Detail screen's View Controller. Navigation bar will automatically update it's label to current View Controller's title.

So if you have action for button :

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSString *title = [button text];
    DetailScreenViewController *detail = [[DetailScreenViewController alloc] initWithDetail:title];
    [detail setTitle:title];
    [navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
    [detail release];
}
```

Comment: I presume DetailScreenViewController will release itself?

Comment: Sorry, I was writing it as a conceptual. I've already changed it.

Answer (score 0):

When updating the view with new content, update the view controller's title:

```
viewController.title = @"New Title";
```

Comment: @Legolas Thanks, I fixed the example.  Not sure what happened.

Answer (score 0):

Before you push the view controller, set the title for it.

```
thisViewController.title = @"My Title";
[navigationController pushViewController: thisViewController animated:YES];
```